# Using multinomial logistic regression to test for heterogeneity

Tags: r, multinomial-logit, heterogeneity

I have been asked to use polychotomous logistic regression to test for heterogeneity or independent variable across multiple outcomes levels, and then change-in-estimate method to identify other factors to adjust for.

My outcome has 4 nominal factors (let's say 1, 2, 3, 4), and my main independent variable has 2 categories (yes/no). When I run my multinomial linear regression model, say:

```
test<- multinom(outcome ~ x1, data)
exp(coef(test))
```

I get coefficients for each level of the outcome (ie. for 1 vs 4, 2 vs 4, 3 vs 4), when what I am looking for (or my boss is looking for) is a single p-value that tests for heterogeneity across the groups. I believe I am doing this wrong, and cannot find how to get this value in R. If anyone could point me towards a help resource, or explain what I have misunderstood, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I think what you want to do is simply to compare model with the yes-no dummy to the model without. Do you think that is right? ... to say you want to test for heterogeneity is kind of vague. Just want to make sure i understand you before i point you in any direction.

Comment: I don't believe so- I think I want to test if there is a statistically significant difference in the effect my variable X1 is having on each outcome. This would provide a general p-value for heterogeneity, as opposed to testing outcomes 2, 3, and 4 with the reference of outcome 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: But if im not mistaken then if there is no heterogeneity between the groups then adding the yes-no dummy to the model does not improve the model and if there is heterogeneity between the groups the adding the dummy does contibute something.

Comment: Hmmm you are right. I will do this instead and see if this is what they were in fact look for, thank you!

Comment: ok let me know if you need help on implementation

Comment: Hi Jesper- I spoke with my supervisor and apparently SAS spits out a single P-value for multinomial LR and R doesn't! So that explains it. In order to compare the models with and without the dummy variable, would you recommend just using anova?